# Icon is not coming in activities

Tags: ios, swift, custom-activity

In my app I have developed custom activity.When user click on more options , it shows the list of activities app.In that list iOS is showing only name of my app , icon is not coming.How to provide the icon for that.

Comment: I have implemented that and that image is coming properly, but if user click on more option then iOS display list of app that have that capability, in that page , icon is not coming.

Comment: Why UIActivity is coming in that more list ??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate asset catalog in your share extensions folder and reference that one in your share extension target. or add main apps asset to Share extension target.

1. Select (extension) Project -> Goto "Build Phase"
2. Expands  "Compile Source"
3. Add "images.xcassests"  (asset where you appicon is ) of your main project
4. Rebuild and run.

Comment: I did not create any extension , just created a activity ( subclass of UIActivity).